# Scrape JSON from script with Selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I have this [webpage](https://ed.team/clase/49/464/2199), and I am trying to get this JSON

[image: JSON]

that "I THINK" is injected by JavaScript... So, getting the response or page_source doesnt work.

In that JSON there's a .m3u8 link thats contains the video... So I want that link for download it.

At the moment I have this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

# options = Options()
# options.headless = True
# driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver = webdriver.Chrome() 

driver.get('https://ed.team/clase/49/464/2199')

usuario = driver.find_element_by_name("email")
usuario.clear()
usuario.send_keys("")

contra = driver.find_element_by_name("password")
contra.clear()
contra.send_keys("")

driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#__next > main > section > form > div:nth-child(3) > input").click() #login button
```

My script only logins into the page and thats all, I dont know how to continue.

If anyone knows how to help me, i will appreciate it a lot! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It'd be a lot easier if you included the contents of the script element and not an image of it in your question.
But nevertheless, get the HTML for that script element, then use `re` module to extract the JSON:

```py
import re
import json

script_html = '''<script>

__NEXT_DATA__ = { 
   "a": "b"
};
'''
# clean up the HTML
script_html = script_html.replace('\n', ' ')

script_re = re.compile(r'__NEXT_DATA__ = ({.*})', flags=re.MULTILINE)
raw_json = script_re.search(script_html).group(1)
parsed = json.loads(raw_json)

print(raw_json)
print(parsed)
```

output:

```
{     "a": "b" }
{'a': 'b'}
```

Comment: Hello sir, I actually know how to interact with the JSON, the point of my question is how to obtain the correct HTML code with the Script in it. Since using driver.page_source only gives me the simple html without content, that’s why I say that the content is injected or generated with JavaScript :/. Please tell me if you understand me.

Comment: Load the page, get the HTML source for the whole page with `driver.page_source` or just the contents of the  `<script>` element using `driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a specific enough selector').get_attribute('innerHTML')`. Since I don't have the HTML, and can't login without an account, I can't help you with finding the right selector. If you update your post  with the source, I'd be happy to help

Comment: Hey, Hello. The source is kinda big. You can create a free account and use the same script I created! But let me try your code first. Thanks.